# How to get JRE path from standalone Java 9 application?

Tags: java, java-9, jlink

I wrote HelloWorld application on Java 9, built him with `jlink` and installed with Inno Setup. I run it with `%path-to-app%/bin/launcher.bat`.

Can I get `%path-to-app%` from Java and show it in console? I think this question can be solved via getting JRE path.

Comment: No. This will show the current user directory from where the program starts

Comment: It added to PATH and user can run this cli app everywhere

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you looking to get the path of the directory that you specify to jlink in the --output option and have it append bin + launcher name ?

Comment: As a result, I would like to have a path to java.exe that already comes with my Java 9 application

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty("java.home");` will give you the path to the JRE.
`System.getProperty(""user.dir");` will give you the current working directory.

Comment: It's Java 9 standalone application. `System.getProperty("java.home")` shows path to JDK. When you built application via `jlink` JRE copy already included to your application.

Comment: @Valeriy No, it should show the path to the image created by jlink. At least I'm getting the directory one up from `bin`.

Comment: @JornVernee I'll try again, but yesterday I got `System.getProperty("java.home")` as my Java 9 JDK path. I ran it under Windows 8.1